# WKWebView do not work with AVAudioSession's category

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, avaudiosession

By setting app's AVAudioSession's category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` with option `mixWithOthers`, will make sounds from video in UIWebView be mixed with third party background music (such as Spotify).

But it do NOT work at all once switch to WKWebView. Code sample:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

/*
 // Mixed background music & video sound in web works with UIWebView
 let webview = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
 self.view.addSubview(webview)
 webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.ultimedia.com/deliver/generic/iframe/mdtk/01509739/src/8l50lp/ad/yes")!))
*/

// Mixed background music & video sound in web do NOT work with WKWebView
let webview = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 300))
self.view.addSubview(webview)
webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.ultimedia.com/deliver/generic/iframe/mdtk/01509739/src/8l50lp/ad/yes")!))

// end of viewDidLoad
```

Code above tested on Xcode 8.2.1, iOS 10.2.1

Any idea or workaround would be really helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution?